# Which is the solution of the limit, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x\sin (\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Which is the solution of the limit,

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$

Comment: Use substitution: $u=\frac{1}{x}$ and note that $x\to\infty\Rightarrow u\to0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this substitution:
$$x=\frac{1}{u},\ u=\frac{1}{x},\ x\rightarrow\infty\Rightarrow u\rightarrow0$$
Hence, your limit changes to:
$$\lim_{u\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{u}\sin(u)=\lim_{u\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}$$
A very known limit.

Answer (score 2):

Put $t= \dfrac 1x \iff x = \dfrac 1t$. And note that as $x\to \infty,\;t\to 0^+$.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x \sin \left(\frac 1x\right) = \lim_{t\to 0^+} \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin \frac1x \sim \frac1x$ as $x\to \infty$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty}x\sin \frac1x = \lim_{x\to \infty}x \frac1x=1 $